# How to use xpath to select a range of nodes from the end?

Tags: xpath

I have a list of nodes.

```
<li>Dont select me</li>
<li>First</li>
...
<li>Last</li>
<li>Dont select me either</li>
```

I know how to select from the start, but I'm not sure how to select a certain number from the end. I won't know how many there are in the list.

So far I have this:

```
//li[position() > 1 and position() < ?]
```

How can I select all of the nodes in the middle, and exclude a certain number from the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `last()` is what you're looking for :

```
//li[position() > 1 and position() < last()]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/a2c8baa5f14eacf33f9cf42e680c5c42)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<result>
<li>First</li>

<li>Last</li>

</result>
```